# Drizzle timestamp datenow invalid default value

Tags: mysql, next.js, planetscale, drizzle

I am new to Drizzle ORM and I am trying to make a simple schema where there is a created_at column that has default value of date of when did the account got created. This is the schema

```
export const users = mysqlTable('users', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
    email: varchar('email', { length: 100 }).notNull(),
    accountType: varchar('accountType', { length: 15 }).references(() => accountTypes.types),
    password: varchar('password', { length: 100 }),
    emailVerified: boolean('verified').default(false),
    verificationToken: varchar('verificationToken', { length: 256 }),
    createdAt: timestamp('created_at').notNull().defaultNow(),
}, (users) => ({
    userIndex: uniqueIndex('user_idx').on(users.email)
})
)
```

I am getting this error whenever I push it to planetscale

```
Error: target: quiz.-.primary: vttablet: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Invalid default value for 'created_at' (errno 1067) (sqlstate 42000) (CallerID: r6e50nzpgoxvw6iizt6g): Sql: "alter table users add UNIQUE INDEX user_idx (email)", BindVars: {REDACTED}
    at PromiseConnection.query (D:\xampp2\htdocs\quiz\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:34740:26)  
    at Command.<anonymous> (D:\xampp2\htdocs\quiz\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:52122:33)      
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ER_INVALID_DEFAULT',
  errno: 1067,
  sql: 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `user_idx` ON `users` (`email`);',
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: `target: quiz.-.primary: vttablet: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Invalid default value for 'created_at' (errno 1067) (sqlstate 42000) (CallerID: r6e50nzpgoxvw6iizt6g): Sql: "alter table users add UNIQUE INDEX user_idx (email)", BindVars: {REDACTED}`
}
```

It was so weird, It says that the default value for created_at is invalid but it still got pushed to my database.

[image: Planetscale console]

Comment: [BUG: unable to set timestamp field to be NOT NULL #657](https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/657)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://www.answeroverflow.com/m/1102406885644189797), the current workaround is to use:

```
default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)
```

Answer (score 2):

`import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";`

and in your table insert this:

```
updatedAt: timestamp("updated_at").default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`),
```

That fixes it!